# Suddenly only 8GB out of 12GB RAM used, despite Memtest86 enumerating all DIMMS when running Proxmox VE 5.2

Tags: memory, bios

I am running a fairly old machine as a home server now, with

- **Motherboard**: Asus Rampge II Extreme
- **CPU**: Intel Core i7 920
- **RAM**: 6 DIMMS, Triple Channel, Corsair CM3X2G1600C8D
- **BIOS**: Tested an old and the current version. Neither indexes all 12GB of RAM.

The machine ran with 12GB RAM correctly enumerated for around 9 years now. Recently I brought the machine to a quiet place to run as a server, installed [Proxmox VE 5.2](https://www.proxmox.com/en/) and by surprise saw, that just 8GB are available to the system.

- All DIMMs sit properly, I even switched them pairwise to double check.
- All DIMMs are of the same type.
- The CMOS battery died and the BIOS reset to the shipped version. I updated it again to the most recent version from 2011. Still just 8GB.
- The BIOS settings are set to default, non-overclocked.
- Memtest86+ 5.01 numerates all 6 DIMMs, but displays only 8183MB as usable (see screenshot), before and after BIOS update and DIMM slot switching.

What could be the problem here? This seems to be a really strange behaviour and I just could find people with mixed or faulty DIMM problems, but none with mine.

[image: Screenshot of Memtest86+ 5.01 enumerating all DIMMs]

Comment: Neither the BIOS nor Memtest show me that 12 GiB are in use, independently from Proxmox VE 5.2. It ran a bunch of different operating system, from Windows 10, over Arch Linux and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took out just one DIMM to test what would happen and voila the BIOS recognized 10 GiB of RAM.

The problem was, that I put out the DIMMS for cleaning a while ago and didn't bother to remember the order of them, because they are all the same model. But they really aren't. They are all of the same model, but of different revisions and oddly enough they don't play together, despite having the same speed, timings and voltage.

- Corsair CM3X2G1600C8D ver2.1 and
- Corsair CM3X2G1600C8D ver5.2

After bringing all DIMMs with the same revision/version in one channel, the computer recognized all 12GiB.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know, what (W13' 09) \*XMP\* means?

Comment: An obvious guess would be when it was manufactured, so `w13 09`, would be the 13th week of 2009.  As for the reason the other modules are not reporting the date, if that is indeed the date, go ask Corsair.  **Memtest can only read what it detects.**  in other words **Garbage in Garbage out**

Answer (score 0):

I guess that with the BIOS reset your settings that reverted to some default
and you have not managed to exactly duplicate the old settings.

I'm rather doubtful about your using
[Intel Extreme Memory Profile (Intel® XMP) and Overclock RAM](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/gaming/extreme-memory-profile-xmp.html)
which might put some limiting constraints on the RAM that can be used.

I suggest that you poke around the BIOS until you find some way of disabling XMP
and try Memtest86+ without it. If nothing changes, please include a new screenshot
for the results.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your though, harrymc. Because I didn't tell, that I took the DIMMs out for dust cleaning, you couldn't know the answer. Do you know why Memtest86+ lists half the DIMMS as \*X.M.P\* and the others as (W13'09) \*X.M.P\*?